# Negation of verb/gerund

Tags: gerunds, negation

I made up the following sentences. Which version is correct?

1. I prefer being by myself and not depend on others.
2. I prefer being by myself and don't depend on others.
3. I prefer being by myself and not depending on others.

The first version looks to me a nice version to hear it. But negation of the verb seems to me wrong.

The senond one looks pretty grammatical.Due to we negate a verb with auxiliary verb *do*

The third one uses gerund. It doesn't nice to hear. But it make sense because it combines the sentence in a good structure: Subject+Verb(Gerund + Gerund)

Comment: You should use the adjective "dependent", as in " I prefer being by myself and not dependent on others".

Comment: @BillJ That is felicitous, but the author seems to tell us that he wants to use the gerund-participle, and to negate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is wrong because "not" can't modify the following "depend". The second and third sentences are grammatically correct but have slightly different meaning.

Sentence 2 describes what I *do* (I *do*n't depend on others) while sentence 3 describes what I *prefer* (I *prefer* not depending on others).